# Замена цвета областей картинки при наведении мыши

Tags: css

Всем привет, прошу помощи.
Вот что есть.
Есть изображение размером `175*251`.
Необходимо, чтобы при наведении на определенную область изображения, эта область изменяла цвет. Для этого под каждую область сделана своя картинка.
На картинку наложен параметр "map", чтобы сделать каждый отдельный объект ссылкой
Вот как примерно должно выглядеть:

[image]

Comment: А вот такой вариант реализации интерактивной карты вам не подходит:
http://htmlbook.ru/blog/postroenie-interaktivnoi-karty-s-raphael ? (внизу страницы демо)

Comment: это сложно.. 
.. сделал с использованием скрипта пипа

<area shape="rect" coords="61,3,141,105" onmouseover="goimg(2)" onmouseout="goimg(0)" href="#"> и т. д.

Comment: Только не могу понять как сделать массив для предзагрузки картинок в кеш браузера..
var imgs = Array()
for (var t=0; t< 6; t++) //для 5 штук
{
imgs[t] = new Image();
imgs[t].src = 'http://картинка'
imgs[t].src = 'http://картинка'
imgs[t].src = 'http://картинка'
imgs[t].src = 'http://картинка'
imgs[t].src = 'http://картинка'
imgs[t].src = 'http://картинка'
} 

Так или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Меняет цвет не сама область, а подменяется все фоновое изображение, на котором эта область с другим цветом.

Подмену можно делать так:

```
<area shape="circle" coords="215,275,10" href="/page.html" title="Московская" onmouseover="document.getElementById('map_bg').src='a.gif'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('map_bg').src='b.gif'">
```

где `map_bg` - `id` фонового изображения, а `area` - одна и областей.

Comment: Да, точно, одна из областей другим цветом. Не могли бы дать ссылку на работающий пример? Не знаю как настроить css и прочее не очень пойму..

Comment: Как сделать тоже самое для нескольких картинок (областей)?
http://kottedzhi-v-finlyandii.ru/map/tesrt.html

Comment: вот здесь так реализовано, но тут не картинка заменяться, тут стоит фоновое изображение где все варианты изображений склеены в один спрайт. а изменяется только позиция фона, стилями.

Answer (score 0):

Если не расписывать подробно, то я бы эту карту сначала разрезал по границам, потом спрайтом оформил до и в момент наведения картинки. Потом при помощи position: relative; собрал в единое целое и через a:hover либо span:hover (background-image) двигал бы нужное поле при наведении.
Рисунок спрайта приблизительно такой
[image]

Прошу прощения вырезал на скорую руку.